# Using pandas style to change the format of header and hide columns

Tags: python, pandas

I want to change the dataframe's format when save it to excel. Right now I know I can do the highlight by style.applymap and add freeze_panes by style.to_excel. Is there any chance I can use the same package to hide some of the columns and save the dataframe with filter on the headers?

Answer (score 0):

As of version 1.5.0 I believe that `Styler.hide()` is not exportable with `Styler.to_excel`, so you cannot hide columns for excel export like you would for HTML or LaTeX.

However, you can easily preselect your dataframe and then apply `Styler` to that.

```py
df = DataFrame({"a": [1,2], "b": [2,3]})
df_select = df[["b"]]  # no "a"
styler=df_select.style
# add styler styles
styler.to_excel()
```

Comment: Thank you! I still want to keep the data when I export them to excel. So I might have to use xlsxwriter to do that right?

Comment: pandas to_excel I dont believe has ability to hide columns, according to excel's hide functionality. If xlsxwriter can implement  this then you will have to use that, otherwise I dont know what else you can do.